# Logistic fit of data

Tags: fitting, data, modeling

I would like to use `LogitModelFit` to find the logistic function to my data.
The error I obtain is

> LogitModelFit::binrsp: The response values are expected to be between
>   0 and 1 for binomial models.

But in the examples, the given values are not in [0,1]. I normalized the values and the error is the same.
Please, help!

Here is the data:

```
data ={{1.887, 17}, {1.9, 44.96}, {1.905, 50.57}, {1.934, 
    79.60}, {1.946, 68.56}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this can be answered without understanding what your data means.  What did you try to normalize your data?

Comment: I want to find the logistic curve which is closest to the given points

Comment: A logistic curve will achieve a maximum value.  Do you know what this value should be?

Comment: The response variable for `LogitModelFit` can only take on the values 0 or 1 or ratios of integer counts if you give the number of binomial trials.  You probably want `NonlinearModelFit` but you should make explicit the "logit" form that you want to fit.  Is that `a/(1+b*Exp[-k t])` or something else?  If that is the case, then fitting 4 parameters (a, b, k, and error variance) with just 5 data points is likely not to be very useful.

Answer (score 6):

You'll likely want `NonlinearModelFit` rather than `LogitModelFit` as the latter assumes that the response variable has a binomial distribution given the prediction model.

Consider the following "logit" model:  $y=a/(1+\exp(-k(t-b)) + e$ where $e\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $a$, $b$, $k$, and $\sigma^2$ are parameters to be estimated.  That's 4 parameters with only 5 data points.  You can't expect very much.

```
data = Rationalize[{{1.887, 17}, {1.9, 44.96}, {1.905, 50.57}, {1.934, 79.60}, {1.946, 68.56}}, 0];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a/(1 +  Exp[-100 k ( t - b)]),
   {{a, 70}, {b, Min[data[[All, 1]]]}, {k, 1.2}}, t, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 74.3454576102087647236067343080, 
    b -> 1.89726015500543769996100150019, 
    k -> 1.17012737566143311476612748243} *)

{tmin, tmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];
mpd = Table[Flatten[{t, FullSimplify[nlm["MeanPredictionBands"]]}],
    {t, tmin, tmax, (tmax - tmin)/100}] // N;

(* Plot of data, fit, and 95% confidence bands for the mean *)
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {All, {-10, 100}}],
 ListPlot[{mpd[[All, {1, 2}]], mpd[[All, {1, 3}]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dotted}, {Blue, Dotted}}, Joined -> True],
 Plot[nlm[t], {t, 1.887, 1.946}]]
```

[image: data, fit, and 95% confidence bands for the mean]

The use of `Rationalize`, `WorkingPrecision -> 30`, and using $a/(1+\exp{(-100k(t-b))}$ rather than $a/(1+\exp{(-100k(t-b))}$ or $a/(1+b\exp{-k t}$ was to keep the calculations from warnings such as "... is too small to represent as a normalized machine number".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just do not understand the meaning of this part
\begin{align*}
{tmin, tmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];
mpd = Table[Flatten[{t, FullSimplify[nlm["MeanPredictionBands"]]}],
    {t, tmin, tmax, (tmax - tmin)/100}] // N;
\end{align*}

Comment: I used that code to avoid several warning messages.  The following produces the same plot (but with lots of warning messages):  `mpb = FullSimplify[nlm["MeanPredictionBands"]]; Plot[{nlm[t], mpb}, {t, 1.885, 1.945}, PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Blue, Dotted}, {Blue, Dotted}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very useful!